# Groovy: Find and replace all node names

Tags: xml, groovy

Considering I have the following XML structure:

```
<Header>
   <Parent1>
       <Line> ABC </Line>
   </Parent1>
   <Parent1>
       <Line> CDE </Line>
   </Parent1>
   <Parent2>
       <Line> EFG </Line>
   </Parent2>
</Header>
```

I would want all `Parent1` parent nodes to be changed to `Parent2`. Like so:

```
<Header>
   <Parent2>
       <Line> ABC </Line>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
       <Line> CDE </Line>
   </Parent2>
   <Parent2>
       <Line> EFG </Line>
   </Parent2>
</Header>
```

Is there a simple way to do this requirement in Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) to do this.

```
def xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Header>
   <Parent1>
       <Line> ABC </Line>
   </Parent1>
   <Parent1>
       <Line> CDE </Line>
   </Parent1>
   <Parent2>
       <Line> EFG </Line>
   </Parent2>
</Header>
'''

def result = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

result.Parent1.replaceNode {
    'Parent2'(it.attributes(), it.children())
}

println(XmlUtil.serialize(result))
```

You can find more information in [XML Processing documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html).

Answer (score 0):

Considering another scenario:

Suppose my XML is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cust_recurring_IT12>
    <cust_recurring_IT12>
        <cust_benevolent>100</cust_benevolent>
        <cust_canteended>0</cust_canteended>
        <externalCode>40012731</externalCode>
        <cust_busded>650</cust_busded>
        <effectiveStartDate>2023-03-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
    </cust_recurring_IT12>
    <cust_recurring_IT12>
        <cust_benevolent>300</cust_benevolent>
        <cust_canteended>0</cust_canteended>
        <externalCode>40012732</externalCode>
        <cust_busded>700</cust_busded>
        <effectiveStartDate>2023-03-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
    </cust_recurring_IT12>
</cust_recurring_IT12>
```

then rename cust_busded to emp_code ---

```
import java.util.*;
import groovy.xml.*;
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil;

def xmlinput = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cust_recurring_IT12>
    <cust_recurring_IT12>
        <cust_benevolent>100</cust_benevolent>
        <cust_canteended>0</cust_canteended>
        <externalCode>40012731</externalCode>
        <cust_busded>650</cust_busded>
        <effectiveStartDate>2023-03-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
    </cust_recurring_IT12>
    <cust_recurring_IT12>
        <cust_benevolent>300</cust_benevolent>
        <cust_canteended>0</cust_canteended>
        <externalCode>40012732</externalCode>
        <cust_busded>700</cust_busded>
        <effectiveStartDate>2023-03-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
    </cust_recurring_IT12>
</cust_recurring_IT12>''';

def rootNode = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(xmlinput);

rootNode.cust_recurring_IT12.children().findAll { it.name().equals('cust_busded') }.replaceNode {
        'emp_code'(it.attributes(), it.children(), it.text())
} 
println XmlUtil.serialize(rootNode);
```

-- output --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cust_recurring_IT12>
  <cust_recurring_IT12>
    <cust_benevolent>100</cust_benevolent>
    <cust_canteended>0</cust_canteended>
    <externalCode>40012731</externalCode>
    <emp_code>650</emp_code>
    <effectiveStartDate>2023-03-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
  </cust_recurring_IT12>
  <cust_recurring_IT12>
    <cust_benevolent>300</cust_benevolent>
    <cust_canteended>0</cust_canteended>
    <externalCode>40012732</externalCode>
    <emp_code>700</emp_code>
    <effectiveStartDate>2023-03-01T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
  </cust_recurring_IT12>
</cust_recurring_IT12>
```